# Find a formula for a vector field with given properties

Tags: multivariable-calculus, circles

This is the exercise:

Give a formula $$F = M(x, y) i+N(x, y)j$$ for the vector
fIeld in the plane that has the properties that $$F =
0$$ at $(0,0)$ and that at any other point $(a,b)$, $F$ is
tangent to the circle $$x^2+y^2 = a^2+b^2$$ and points in the
clockwise direction with magnitude $$F =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

I don't understand how $x^2+y^2 = a^2+b^2$ can be a circle when $(a,b)$ is a point i.e $(x,y)$..
then $x^2+y^2 =x^2+y^2$  ....the solution is $$yi + -xj$$ and i dont understand how that vector is tangent to the circle

Answer (score 2):

$(a,b)$ is a point but if you view $\mathbb R^{2}$ as a vector space, the square of the magnitude of $(a,b)$ is $ |(a,b)|^{2} = a^2 + b^2$. That's why $x^2+y^2 = a^2+b^2$ defines a circle.

If $F = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, this just says that that the magnitude of the vector field at $(a,b)$ is equal to the distance from $(a,b)$ to $(0,0)$.

The tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius of the circle.
If $(x,y)$ is any point in the plane, we can represent it as $(x,y) = x(1,0) + y(0,1) = xi + yj$. A vector $v$ perpendicular to this must be such that $v\cdot (x,y) = 0$. We also require the magnitude to equal $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. There are two obvious candidates, $(-y,x)$ and $(y,-x)$. One of these points in the clockwise direction and the other points in the counter-clockwise direction. If you draw a point in the first quadrant along with the two candidate vectors you'll see that $yi + -xj$ is the clockwise one.